# Including certificate of completing a training course in resume Certificates section

Tags: resume, certification

Let's say I have had a training course and completed it with a final exam, then the institute has given me a certification for completing the course with a grade of "X". Certification like:

> This is to certify that
> "Amir Mahdi Nassiri"
> has successfully completed the requirements for the
> "SQL Server 2014 Database Development"
> course and has received the following score: X
>   Duration: 60 Hrs.
>   Completion Date: YYYY/MM/DD
>   Date of Issue: YYYY/MM/DD

Should I include this certification to my resume's Certificates And Skills section? What is the best way to include this detail?

I'm creating the resume for academical purposes and to attend post graduate studies.

By "the best way" I mean is Certificates And Skills section the best place to put the info? And what info of the certificate I should mention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I include this certification to my resume's Certificates And Skills section?

Yes you can, but include it **only if you are applying to a job where that certificate is a relevant thing to include** in your resume; otherwise it's just noise to you application.

> What is the best way to include this detail?

Don't know if the *best*, but a way of including it could be something like: *"[Completion Date] - Completed the SQL Server 2014 Database Development course - Final Score: X"*

---

**Update:** Similar situation when using it for academic applications. I would be better if you include it if you are applying to a career or studies where that sort of certification would be relevant. However, given that this is also academic experience I would say you should definitely include it anyways, as that is the sort of things Universities want to see on their potential candidates.

Including it under your Certificates section is fine, but that could also go in your Education section, as it is something you did to invest in your education.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply :)
I edited my question to add my purpose of writing the resume. Would you mind read it again? I'll appreciate it.

Comment: @AmirMahdiNassiri umm.. I don't see any updates you say

Comment: Sorry I replied to your post and then edited my question :D

Comment: @AmirMahdiNassiri I see no problem :) updated my answer

Comment: I should really thank you for your great detailed answer. I'm afraid I'm a newbie here and can not up-vote your answer publicly :) Can you please answer my second edit as well?

Comment: @AmirMahdiNassiri just did :) Also, I must say that for future reference, I suggest you refrain from accepting an answer when you still are thinking of editing your post. Not only is a bit confusing (even a bit unfair for users that are not engaged to see your edits), but people will refrain from including more answers to your post that could also prove helpful to you (as they may think, well this Q has already an accepted Answer, and walk away). Sometimes its better to leave the post unaccepted, and some time later return and accept the answer you want. Glad I could help, good luck.

Comment: Oh I see. You're right! I really did check as answer to appreciate your super fast answer :D I was so desperate when asking the question :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I personally would put that under an **education section** rather than a certification\Skills section.

In that section you can list the course name and Completion date.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. Isn't putting it under education section feel like a little exaggeration?

Comment: @AmirMahdiNassiri No, its a Class you took. See https://bizfluent.com/how-10039290-list-training-received-resume.html

Comment: @AmirMahdiNassiri I agree with Morons (lol?), its something you did to invest in your education. Including it there would make sense.

Comment: @Morons The link you pointed out mentions: **Include training you received in the “Education” section of your resume if you have only one or a few certificates or credentials**. Does hardly three certificates belong to this category? Or individual section should be preferred?